# How to gradually count down to zero over a changeable duration in Java?

Tags: java, math, timer

I have a timer of X seconds, and I want Y to count down to zero in even spaces of time, reaching 0 at the same time the timer finishes.

For example, If I had a timer of 10 seconds, and a value of 20, I would want the value to go down by 2 every second.

The timer would preferably update quickly as it will be displayed as a bar.

Thank you for your help!

For context, here is the timer I am using:

```java
public EventTimer(int seconds) {
        // Start timer
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds*1000);
        cooledDown = false;
    }

    class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            // Ends timer
            timer.cancel(); //Terminate the timer thread
            cooledDown = true;
        }
```

- Roman

Edit:
I know that I could just set another timer but my main goal here is to decrement gradually

Comment: What if Y is 17, should it count down by a fractional amount or should it sometimes count down by 2 and sometimes by 1? Or will this never happen

Comment: Ideally a fractional amount, sorry for not specifying!

Comment: which UI framework do you work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this.

```
public class Counter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int inSeconds = 5;
        int countTo = 10;
        countToInSeconds(inSeconds, countTo);
    }

    public static void countToInSeconds(double inSeconds, double countTo) throws InterruptedException {

        // Throw Exception if invalid args
        if (countTo < 0 || inSeconds < 0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("CountTo and inSeconds must be positive");
        }

        // Calculated lerp time
        long lerpTime = (long) (1000 / (countTo / inSeconds));

        // Count to countTo in inSeconds
        for (int i = 1; i <= countTo; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            Thread.sleep(lerpTime);
        }

        System.out.println("Done! Counted to " + countTo + " in " + inSeconds + " seconds :D");
    }
}
```

It is just a regular timer using Thread.sleep but with a calculated lerp time.

```
// This code calculates the wait Time between the sysout statement
long lerpTime = (long) (1000 / (countTo / inSeconds));
```

So normally we would wait 1000ms (1 second) on each iteration. But by dividing countTo by inSeconds we get the actual time to wait before the next sysout call which is 0.5 seconds. Now we just take the 1000ms (1 seconds) and divide it by 0.5 to get the actual wait time in milliseconds which is 500.

Answer (score 1):

The fraction of `Y` when `T` time is left is `Y*T/X`. Here's a simple TimerTask that ticks X times, going from Y (exclusive) down to 0.0 (inclusive).

If you want to show this in a GUI you'll have to figure out how to publish the current value to your UI framework. Remember that `run()` runs in the timer thread, not in the GUI framework thread, so you can't directly modify the UI from TimerTask.

```
class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
    private int y;
    private int x;
    private int ticksLeft;

    public RemindTask(int Y, int X) {
        y = Y;
        x = X;
        ticksLeft = X;
    }
    public void run() {
        ticksLeft = ticksLeft - 1;
        double currentValue = (double) y*ticksLeft/x;
        System.out.println(currentValue);
        if (ticksLeft == 0) {
            cancel();
        }
    }
}
```